# PowerMockito: Trying to mock System class methods or any other Final class method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am trying to mock System class to get a constant value for currentTimeMillis().
Since I cannot use Mockito for mocking final classes I am using PowerMock, but when mocking the System.currentTimeMillis() I am geting error "Cannot resolve method when(long)".

My code looks like:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(CURRENT_TIME_STAMP);
```

I have also annoted my class as:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class DateTimeUtilsTest {
```

Comment: How about treating it as 3rd party dependency / implementation concern and encapsulating it behind an abstraction that can be easily implemented and mocked/stubbed.

Comment: I had better experience with jmockit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

It should be like

```
PowerMockito.when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(CURRENT_TIME_STAMP);
```

or import the PowerMockito statically like

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
```

Similarly, one can mock any of the System class methods or can mock any other final class.

Answer (score 1):

This is why you should write tests first, then you don't write untestable code.

Your code should not access transient statics directly, but through a component you can mock.